# Websocket not connected - why?

Tags: android, sockets, websocket

I try to connected web socket in my android application for this http://192.168.0.6:8989/websocket URl but nothing get any response like error or success.

I am using stomp web-socket library but no success found.

'''// connectWebSocket();

```
    // Create a WebSocket factory and set 5000 milliseconds as a timeout
    // value for socket connection.
    WebSocketFactory factory = new WebSocketFactory().setConnectionTimeout(5000);

    // Create a WebSocket. The timeout value set above is used.
    try {
        ws =factory.createSocket("http://192.168.0.6:8989/websocket");

        ws.addListener(new WebSocketAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onTextMessage(WebSocket websocket, String message) throws Exception {
                Log.d("TAG", "onTextMessage: " + message);
            }
        });

        ws.connectAsynchronously();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }'''
```

compile 'com.neovisionaries:nv-websocket-client:2.4'

Comment: Is this url accessible from the mobile client? I mean is it accessible via Internet? If not then you need to create proxy for that.

Comment: How to create proxy for this URL

Comment: There are couple of ways to do that. If your webservice is running on Tomcat at the same system then you need to use Android Emulator and setup the proxy things. If your webservice is accessible on same network as your device is connected then again you need to do the setup things. Hope this may help. Better you can deploy your service on public domain for better testing.